# can't i just use a standard query to fetch the message in the database to whichever user i want instead of using sockets, what is the issue with that

Tags: database, sockets, chat

if i push messages to database through simple form insert and retrieve them through a simple query from database wouldnt that qualify as a chat system so to say? just a question i'm using wappler and theres issues with socket i cant seem to get around and i just thought about doing this as a workaround but i have no further knowledge of what could go wrong or whether there are actually rules for creating chat possibilities in websites or apps

i actually tried pushing messages through the socket emit component which does insert the message in the database but on the socket message event (defining what happens when new message is received) i wanted to now load the message to the client but this does not work but when i add the load serverconnect event on the submit button the message is displayed as expected i dont know if this should be good or whether is a potential mistake to continue in this fashion